# Why does Qt use arrow syntax?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a reason why Qt decided to replace the . with ->? Is there a technical reason why we do:

```
ui->statusBar->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```

instead of

```
ui.statusBar.setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```

?

Comment: Qt didn't really decide to switch dots with arrows. It decided to use pointers.

Comment: It's not arbitrary syntax; "->" is pointer dereferencing, "." isn't.

Comment: @chris: Is there a reason why it uses pointers?

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't work on objects.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: So I'm guessing C++ doesn't support polymorphism but Qt does?

Comment: @user2370738 C++ has pointers...

Comment: @user2370738 Qt is just a library. It doesn't change the principles and syntax of the language...

Comment: You don't always have to use pointers with Qt, it is just the preferred style, which stems from implementation of automatic deletition of child objects and using pointers is just more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a choice of Qt, but the way proper design in C++ works. `->` dereferences a pointer to an object to access a member of it. Passing a pointer around tends to be the cleanest method of access to an object.